# Persist few key-value pairs

Tags: xml, hashmap, key-value

I have about 10 key-value pairs which I need to persist. As it is not big I surely don't want to go with a database. So I was thinking of a simple java Hashmap. But then how can I persist it?

The other option could be an xml file, but then I have the difficulty of parsing it.

Which one do you recommend. Or any other solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: May I ask what is your difficulty parsing XML because it sure is a good option to use. Just load at start and keep its DOM in memory as long as the application is running and use it when needed.

Comment: Thanks Avkash, I was thinking something very simple like a map. So for now I am trying java preferences. It persists key-values in the memory. Like in the registry. And I can simply access them with put and get method. If I wasn't successful with this one I would go with xml solution. Tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally ended up using java preferences API.

It persists the key-value pairs somewhere based on your Operating System. We can use put and get methods just like Map. I ran it once and it was persisted on my OS.

Thanks.